# Retrieve all Embedded resources is not working in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using "Retrieve all Embedded resources" advanced option to retrieve all static content.
It work fine but does not retrieve below .js. Is there any Filter or option in JMeter to get below files ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any "below .js", just in case be aware of the following limitation:

As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.** Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

so if an "embedded resource" is being triggered by the client-side JavaScript - JMeter won't be able to process the JavaScript hence won't download the associated piece of content. If this is your case - you will need to download it using a separate [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apaache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and put both "main" HTTP Request and the second one under the [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) to get the cumulative time. If there are multiple occurrences of such assets - put them under a [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter/)